# PHP Daily bonus

Tags: php, sql, date

I need to code daily bonus system.
User must be able to recieve bonus once a day.
I coded something like that:

```
function checkDailyBonus($user, $type) {
    global $ado;
    $last_day = strtotime(date("Y:m:d 00:00:00"));

    $query = $ado->exec("SELECT * FROM claimed_bonuses WHERE `user` = '$user' and `type` = '$type' ORDER BY `id` DESC");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $date = strtotime($row['date']);
    if ($ado->count($query) < 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        if ($last_day < $date) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

But its returning the wrong result: even if today is higher that last claim bonus script returns 0, but it should be returning 1 instead. The last claim date is 2013-05-19 23:05:41. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Looks like you're begging for SQL injection.

Comment: How are you accessing the database? Is your `exec` function returning something that you can pass to `mysql_fetch_assoc()`?

Comment: @John, that would be true if `$type` and `$user` were user input, but there is no indication of that here.

Comment: i would throw a limit 1 onto the query for performance or just select where `date > '<?= date("Y-m-d")'` and check the count

Comment: Have you done some debugging to see where the problem is? Also, I'd advise fixing your indentation - it really does make life a _lot_ easier.

Comment: my exec function is: mysql_query() function.

Comment: It may help to remove the time part as the future is always 1 second away.

Comment: Can you explian what `$ado->exec()` does?  Does it return a result set handle compatiblewith `mysql_fetch_assoc()`? have you checked to make you are not getting any errors on the query/connection?

Comment: I dont have any idea how to chech if user has claimed bonus today. If yes script should return 0, if no 1 and if its next day it also should return 1

Comment: @Mike Brant sql and query is ok

Comment: You'd be better off setting up a cron job to award a bonus to everyone who is eligible and have it run once per day - a much simpler and probably safer option in my opinion.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

umm, why not.

```
SELECT ..
FROM claimed_bonuses
WHERE DATE(lastbonus) < CURDATE()
```

It is beyond pointless to all those strtotime calls and filter the entire user table in PHP when you can have MySQL do it much more simply directly in the query...

Comment: I dont have any idea how to chechk if user has claimed bonus today. If yes script should return 0, if no 1 and if its next day it also should return 1

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your database structure I can't write this for you but I would recommend doing this in your query like:

For the current day:

```
SELECT * FROM claimed_bonuses
WHERE `user` = '$user' and `type` = '$type'
AND date_format(`date`, '%Y%b%e') = date_format(now(), '%Y%b%e')
```

Then just check if it returned a row or not.

Comment: uh, why all the string formatting,w hen you can compare dates directly? date(dateifled) = date(otherdatefield)?

Comment: I ned to check if user claimed bonus in current day and return 1 if no and 0 if yes

Comment: in this case because i took that from a code snippet i had where i needed to do that for other reasons, it was part of something larger and i deleted the rest that had to do with me looping through stuff. i suppose it doesn't really matter either way. i agree that there's no reason to do this outside of the SQL in his case.

Comment: Michal, just do `$didntHaveBonusToday = (int)(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0);` or something to that effect